# scala - reset to 1 when the duplicated value changes in a list

Tags: scala

I'm trying to generate sequence numbers on duplicated elements. It should reset to 1 when the value changes,

```
val dt = List("date", "date", "decimal", "decimal", "decimal", "string", "string")
var t = 0
dt.sorted.map( x => {t=t+1; (x,t)} )
```

This gives result as

```
List((date,1), (date,2), (decimal,3), (decimal,4), (decimal,5), (string,6), (string,7))
```

But what I expect is to get it as

```
List((date,1), (date,2), (decimal,1), (decimal,2), (decimal,3), (string,1), (string,2))
```

how do I change the value of t to 0 when the value changes in my list?.

Are there better methods to get the above output?.

Comment: What if you had `List("date","string","date")`? `List(("date",1),("string",1),("date",1))`? Is the result order significant?

Comment: @jwvh.. no.. that's the reason I used ````sorted```` in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best method to use for this is `scanLeft` which is like `foldLeft` but emits a value at each step. The code looks like this:

```
val ds = dt.sorted
ds.tail.scanLeft((ds.head, 1)){
  case ((prev, n), cur)  if prev == cur => (cur, n+1)
  case (_, cur) => (cur, 1)
}
```

At each step it increments the count if the value is the same as the previous, otherwise it resets it to 1.

---

This will work if the list has a single element. Although `tail` will be `Nil`, the first element in the result of `scanLeft` is always be the first parameter to the method. In this case it is `(ds.head, 1)`.

This will **not** work if the list is empty, as `ds.head` will throw an exception. This can be fixed by using a `match` first:

```
ds match {
  case head :: tail =>
    tail.scanLeft((head, 1)) {
      case ((prev, n), cur) if prev == cur => (cur, n + 1)
      case (_, cur) => (cur, 1)
    }
  case _ => Nil
}
```

Comment: with just one element also, it works.. how is it?. the ds.tail returns empty list..right?.. could you please shed some light

Comment: could you pls have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929119/scala-get-running-count-of-words-in-a-list-with-order-preserved/55929398?noredirect=1#comment98517693_55929398

Answer (score 3):

To reset the counter you need to look back at the previous element, which `.map()` can't do.

```
dt.foldLeft(List.empty[(String,Int)]){ case (lst,str) =>
    lst.headOption.fold((str,1)::Nil){
      case (`str`,cnt) => (str,cnt+1) :: lst
      case _           => (str,1)     :: lst
    }
}.reverse
//res0: List[(String, Int)] = List((date,1), (date,2), (decimal,1), (decimal,2), (decimal,3), (string,1), (string,2))
```

---

**explanation**

- `foldLeft` - consider the `dt` elements, one at a time, left to right
- `List.empty[(String,Int)]` - we'll build a `List` of tuples, start with an empty list
- `case (lst,str)` - the list we're building and the current `String` element from `dt`
- `lst.headOption` - get the head of the list if it exists
- `fold((str,1)::Nil)` - if `lst` is empty return a new list with a single element
- `case (str,cnt)` - if the head string element is the same as the current `dt` element
- `(str,cnt+1) :: lst` - add a new element, with incremented count, to the list
- `case _` - head string element is different from the current `dt` element
- `(str,1) :: lst` - add a new element, with count = 1, to the list
- `.reverse` - we've built the results in reverse order, reverse it

Comment: could you please add some explanation.. there is nested fold and how it works?

Comment: @stack0114106; explanation added

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps.

```
scala> val dt = List("date", "date", "decimal", "decimal", "decimal", "string", "string")
dt: List[String] = List(date, date, decimal, decimal, decimal, string, string)

scala> val dtset = dt.toSet
dtset: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(date, decimal, string)

scala> dtset.map( x => dt.filter( y => y == x))
res41: scala.collection.immutable.Set[List[String]] = Set(List(date, date), List(decimal, decimal, decimal), List(string, string))

scala> dtset.map( x => dt.filter( y => y == x)).flatMap(a => a.zipWithIndex)
res42: scala.collection.immutable.Set[(String, Int)] = Set((string,0), (decimal,1), (decimal,0), (string,1), (date,0), (date,1), (decimal,2))

scala> dtset.map( x => dt.filter( y => y == x)).flatMap(a => a.zipWithIndex).toList
res43: List[(String, Int)] = List((string,0), (decimal,1), (decimal,0), (string,1), (date,0), (date,1), (decimal,2)) // sort this list to your needs
```

Answer (score 2):

By adding one more mutable string variable, the below one works.

```
val dt = List("date", "date", "decimal", "decimal", "decimal", "string","string")
var t = 0
var s = ""
val dt_seq = dt.sorted.map( x => { t= if(s!=x) 1 else t+1;s=x; (x,t)} )
```

Results:

```
dt_seq: List[(String, Int)] = List((date,1), (date,2), (decimal,1), (decimal,2), (decimal,3), (string,1), (string,2))
```

Another way is to use groupBy(identity) and get the indices from map values

```
val dt = List("date", "date", "decimal", "decimal", "decimal", "string","string")
val dtg = dt.groupBy(identity).map( x => (x._2 zip x._2.indices.map(_+1)) ).flatten.toList
```

which results in

```
dtg: List[(String, Int)] = List((decimal,1), (decimal,2), (decimal,3), (date,1), (date,2), (string,1), (string,2))
```

Thanks to @Leo, instead of indices, you can use `Stream from 1` with zip that gives the same results.

```
val dtg = dt.groupBy(identity).map( x => (x._2 zip (Stream from 1)) ).flatten.toList
```

Comment: You could replace `x._2 zip x._2.indices.map(_+1)` with `x._2 zip (Stream from 1)`.