# scala - get running count of words in a list with order preserved

Tags: scala

I'm trying to get the running count of words in a list by preserving the order of the elements

```
scala> val a = List("she","sells","seashells","by","the","seashore","the", "shells", "she", "sells", "are", "surely", "seashells","where", "are", "the", "shells")
a: List[String] = List(she, sells, seashells, by, the, seashore, the, shells, she, sells, are, surely, seashells, where, are, the, shells)

scala> a.map( x => (x,a.count(_ == x)))
res13: List[(String, Int)] = List((she,2), (sells,2), (seashells,2), (by,1), (the,3), (seashore,1), (the,3), (shells,2), (she,2), (sells,2), (are,2), (surely,1), (seashells,2), (where,1), (are,2), (the,3), (shells,2))

scala>
```

But what I want is

```
List((she,1), (sells,1), (seashells,1), (by,1), (the,1), (seashore,1), (the,2), (shells,1), (she,2), (sells,2), (are,1), (surely,1), (seashells,2), (where,1), (are,2), (the,3), (shells,2))
```

Tried something like below, but it is throwing error

```
scala> a.scanLeft(scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int]()){ (x,t) => {x(t) = x(t)+1; (x) } }
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: she
  at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
  at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.apply(HashMap.scala:65)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:13)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:13)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$scanLeft$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:374)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$scanLeft$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:374)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.scanLeft(TraversableLike.scala:374)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.scanLeft(Traversable.scala:104)
  ... 32 elided

scala>
```

Comment: Try FoldLeft operation instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A rather convoluted `foldLeft` appears to work.

```
a.foldLeft((List.empty[(String,Int)],Map[String,Int]().withDefaultValue(0))){
  case ((lst,cnts),s) => ((s,cnts(s)+1) :: lst, cnts + ((s,cnts(s)+1)))
}._1.reverse
//res0: List[(String, Int)] = List((she,1), (sells,1), (seashells,1), (by,1), (the,1), (seashore,1), (the,2), (shells,1), (she,2), (sells,2), (are,1), (surely,1), (seashells,2), (where,1), (are,2), (the,3), (shells,2))
```

Comment: thank you... I tried passing Map followed by List in the foldLeft..it is throwing error..`a.foldLeft((Map[String,Int]().withDefaultValue(0),List.empty[(String,Int)]) {  ((m,lst),s) => m+(s,m(s)+1),(s,m(s)+1)::lst  }._2.reverse`.. could you please help to fix this?

Comment: Four errors: 1 - Missing close-paren `)` before the curly-brace `{`. 2 - Missing `case` keyword after the curly-brace `{`. 3 - Parens are needed around the `=>` result tuple, else-wise it's not a tuple. 4 - Another paren set `()` is needed to make the tuple that gets added to the `Map` : `m+((s,m(s)+1))`. Without that, it looks like you're trying to pass 2 arguments to the `+()` method, which obviously isn't correct.

Comment: yea.. finally, this worked.. ````a.foldLeft((Map[String,Int]().withDefaultValue(0),List.empty[(String,Int)])) { case ((m,lst),s) => ( m+((s,m(s)+1)),(s,m(s)+1)::lst ) }._2.reverse````

Comment: any reason why ````a.scanLeft(scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int]().withDefaultValue(0) ){ (x,t) => ((t,x(t)+1)) }```` is not working?.. giving type mismatch error

Comment: The zero element is a `Map[String,Int]`, therefore the result of the `(x,t) =>` computation needs to be a `Map[String,Int]` because the result of each computation is passed to the next iteration. An easy mod, to get the right type, would be `=> x + ((t,x(t)+1))`, but it won't get you the results you're after. I don't think it can be done with `scan`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version using the same principles as your original code:

```
a.reverse.tails.collect{case s :: t => (s, t.count(_ == s) + 1)}.toList.reverse
```

But this is slow and inefficient for long lists, so I would go with the previous answer!

The most efficient solution would use a mutable `Map` and `ListBuffer`, but that seems like overkill in this case:

```
def wordCount(s: List[String]): List[(String, Int)] = {
  val wordMap = collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, Int].withDefaultValue(0)
  val res = collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[(String, Int)]

  s.foreach{ s =>
    wordMap(s) += 1
    res += s -> wordMap(s)
  }

  res.toList
}
```

Comment: can you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55917665/scala-replace-2nd-and-4th-occurence-using-regex especially, I want to avoid mutable variable c in one of the answer